# flask: Writing directly to response stream

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask

Hej all,

I've got an flask restplus server in place and I am trying to achieve to deliver excel as an octet-stream to my clients. It seems that pandas.to_excel(..) consumes a lot of time (30 secs for about 120k rows) when serializing large DataFrames.

Please see below my current implementation:

```
def format(data_frame):
    # Idea is to directly write to the flask output stream, instead of buffering
    # the whole excel as io.BytesIO. Is there a way to do it?
    output = io.BytesIO()
    writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    data_frame_ordered = data_frame.reindex_axis(sorted(data_frame.columns), axis=1)

    # This consumes a lot of time
    data_frame_ordered.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='ML Data', na_rep=0, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

    # This consumes a lot of time, too.
    writer.save()

    return output.getvalue()


@api.route('/excel', methods=['GET'])
class ExcelResource(Resource):
    def get(self, args):
        # Well, thats a huge pandas.DataFrame
        data_frame = ...
        resp = make_response(format(data_frame))
        resp.headers['Content-Length'] = resp.content_length
        resp.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'

        return resp
```

Is there a way to write the excel directly to the flask output stream, without buffering it into an BytesIO instance?

Thanks in advance

Dennis

Answer (score 2):

You can try to create some file-like object that will provide streaming interface to you, like:

```
import threading
from flask import Response
from Queue import Queue


class StreamWriter(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = Queue()

    def write(self, some):
        self.queue.put(some)

    def read(self):
        return self.queue.get(True)

    def flush(self):
        pass

    def tell(self):
        #probably some code
        pass

    def seek(self):
        #probably some code
        pass

    def close(self):
        self.queue.put(None)

@api.route('/excel', methods=['GET'])
class ExcelResource(Resource):
    def get(self, args):
        def generate():
            output = StreamWriter()

            def do_stuff():
                output = StreamWriter()

                writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
                data_frame_ordered = data_frame.reindex_axis(sorted(data_frame.columns), axis=1)

                # This consumes a lot of time
                data_frame_ordered.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='ML Data', na_rep=0, index=False, encoding='utf-8')

                # This consumes a lot of time, too.
                writer.save()
                output.close()

            threading.Thread(target=do_stuff).start()
            while True:
                chunk = output.read()
                if chunk is None:
                    break
                yield chunk

        return Response(generate(), headers={some_headers})
```

*It's just a rough idea, and this code is untested!*